# can't get data-id for every div with data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get every id inside data-id of every div in a specific div. As a result, I get [7,7,7,7] but I only have 3 divs with different data-id?

Here's my html :

```
<div id="activated_blocs">
  <div class="bloc-row" data-id="7">
  <div class="bloc-row" data-id="9">
  <div class="bloc-row" data-id="8">
</div>
```

Here's my jquery, which is not working...

```
var good_order = $('#activated_blocs').find('.bloc-row');
    var test_array = [];
    $.each(good_order, function() {
        test_array.push(good_order.data('id'));
    });
    console.log(test_array);
```

How to get my array with [7,9,8] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in the loop, you need to use the current element, `good_order` is a jQuery object referring to multiple elements, calling `.data('id')` on it will always return the `data-id` value of the first element in that set.

```js
var good_order = $('#activated_blocs').find('.bloc-row');
var test_array = good_order.map(function() {
  return $(this).data('id')
}).get();
snippet.log(JSON.stringify(test_array));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<div id="activated_blocs">
  <div class="bloc-row" data-id="7"></div>
  <div class="bloc-row" data-id="9"></div>
  <div class="bloc-row" data-id="8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, I totally forget about $(this). Thanks!